# Spring does not create ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, bean-validation

Spring does not create an instance of class implementing `ConstraintValidator`.
Even when I annotate `RolesValidator` with `@Configuartion` Spring create its instance, but validation doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = [RolesValidator::class])
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY, AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ValidateRoles(
    val message: String = "{com.app.authservice.validators.ValidateRoles.message}",
    val groups: Array<KClass<*>> = arrayOf(),
    val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = arrayOf()
)

//------Validator------

class RolesValidator : ConstraintValidator<ValidateRoles, Collection<String>> {
    lateinit var allowedValues: List<String>

    override fun initialize(constraintAnnotation: ValidateRoles?) {
        allowedValues = RoleType.values().map { it.name }
    }

    override fun isValid(value: Collection<String>?, context: ConstraintValidatorContext?): Boolean {
        return allowedValues.containsAll(value!!)
    }
}

//------Usage------

class AccountUpdateRolesDTO {
    @NotNull
    @ValidateRoles
    var roles: Set<String> = emptySet()
}

//------Controller------

@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority($_ADMIN)")
@Transactional
@PutMapping("/{accountId}/roles")
fun updateRoles(
    @RequestBody @Valid body: AccountUpdateRolesDTO,
    @PathVariable accountId: Long,
    jwt: JWTData
): ResponseEntity<Void> {
    return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

@edit https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21242 (formerly SPR-16701)

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in log? How do you now that that's not created?

Comment: I setup a break point in the Validator and it's never invoked nor initialized. And no, no exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leverage [annotation use-site targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets), Kotlin tests pass as well:

```
class KotlinBodyDTO {
    @field:NotNull
    @field:ValidateRolesKotlin
    var roles: Set<String> = emptySet()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Spring doesn't recognize annotations in Kotlin. After I converted the annotation to Java everything was ok.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = RolesValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface ValidateRoles {
    String message() default "{com.app.authservice.validators.ValidateRoles.message}";

    Class[] groups() default {};

    Class[] payload() default {};
}
```